# event.stopPropagation(); doesn't behave as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, stoppropagation

I read couple articles related to `event.stopPropagation();` but none of the solutions provided works for me.
Basically what I have is an accordion widget with all the elements collapsed by default. On each element header (dt tag) there is also a checkbox. Clicking the checkbox shouldn't trigger the accordion to make its elements expand.

```
<dt data-toggle="collapse">
<span class="subscribe-checkbox"><button type="button" class="btn toggle-btn" data-toggle="button"></button></span>
</dt>
<dd>
<p>Accordion content...</p>
</dd>
```

Clicking the span (which should act as a checkbox) should add class "checked" to it. However it also expands the accordion element (dd tag).
What I'm doing in jQuery is:

```
$('.accordion-group .btn.toggle-btn').click(function (event) {
event.stopPropagation();
});
```

While the accordion content isn't shown (which is good) the `<span>` element doesn't change class either, so it doesn't become 'checked'.
I tried with `.live()` too and didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `addEventListener` and then use the boolean `Capture` argument to control the behaviour of parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

stopPropagation() does not work because the `<dd>` is not a parent to the `<span>`, so the event does not propagate from the `<span>` to the `<dd>`.

You'll have to restructure the handlers a little bit, maybe remove the click handler for the parent element of this whole code, and add a new handler for the `<dd>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
So behavior is:
- click on <dt> and <dd> is displayed.
- click on <span> which is inside of <dt> , span becomes checked and <dd> not shown

So I think the problem is with <dt> and not with <dd> and <p>. Because the click event is propagated on the <dt> which is the parent of the span.. Is there something am I missing?

Comment: I think you need to show more code, what other click handlers do you have in place?